# How can I call a library function just from its name?

Tags: c

I want to be able to use a `char *function_name = "foo"` to call `foo()` from a C program.  The `foo()` routine would be in a shared library.  I don't have access to any dlopen, etc, just the load step for a regular executable.  Is there any way to resolve this name and load it from the shared library?

Comment: As pascal pointed out, this question really needs a tag for the OS or OS family. (Probably POSIX..?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You either use `dlopen` and `dlsym`, or you make your own array of function names and function pointers and look it up that way.

Comment: `dlsym` can take the pseudo-handle `RTLD_DEFAULT`, so `dlopen` may not be necessary.

Comment: Indeed, I should have mentioned that. Keep in mind it will not find symbols defined in the main program unless you linked using `-rdynamic`.

Comment: I thought this was the case, but had to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this unless you have access to the function names and load addresses. You can do this using `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` in Windows.

In your case, I don't know exactly what you have available (you didn't mention your platform, compiler, etc.) or if this is feasible. I strongly suspect, however, that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The common method to call functions by name is to use a table of names and function pointers.  A caveat to this technique is that the functions must all have the same signature.

If you know the names functions but the function signatures differ, you will have to use and `if-then-else` ladder.

Comment: They do not need to have the same signature, just the same return type. You can use `rettype (*)()` as the function type (instead of a prototype) and then you're responsible to passing the right argument types when you call it. Or, since all function pointer types are guaranteed to survive round-trip casts to other function pointer types, you could just use `void (*)()` for them all and cast them to the right type before calling them.